# Grub 2 Password Protection in debian?

Tags: debian, password-protection, grub

I do as the following

1. run  grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 to get  a string
2. nano  /boot/grub/grub.cfg
3. add two lines
4. set superusers="putyourusernamehere"
5. password putyourusernamehere grub.pbkdf2  (omitted)

When I reopen my computer,it can't work,how can I take  grub 2 Password Protection  in debian ?

Answer (score 3):

Debian 8 (jessie) stores Grub 2 password parameters within the directory `/etc/grub.d/` . Inside this directory there are only **scripts** used to generate the configuration file.

So you can create a new script (e.g. `/etc/grub.d/01_users` ) with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF
set superusers="putyourusernamehere"
password putyourusernamehere grub.pbkdf2 grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.3450C89...
EOF
```

All the above lines are part of the file, because it is a script whose output will go in the final configuration file. Since it is a script, it will only be processed if it is executable (`chmod a+x ...`).

As an **alternative**, you may put just the lines you need in one of the existing files that are tweaked to output their own contents. Here you can see how `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` substitutes the shell with a tail command returning script contents starting from the third line:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

set superusers="putyourusernamehere"
password putyourusernamehere grub.pbkdf2 grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.3450C89...
```

**In some Ubuntu derivatives (e.g. Mint 19) the format of the password changed as follows:**

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

set superusers=putyourusernamehere
password_pbkdf2 putyourusernamehere grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.3450C89...
```

You may want to add "--unrestricted" to the menu entries you want to boot without a password. For example within the file `10_linux` :

```
10_linux:CLASS="--class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted"
```

Finally launch `update-grub2` to generate the final configuration file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` .

Comment: Do you mean `cat << EOF`?

Comment: @G-Man indeed txs

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords). Official documentation from the debian-based OS: Ubuntu. Maybe it can help